# Python cant find database if script is run from other file

Tags: python, sqlite, data-science

**Solved in comment**

I have this struggle with a dataheavy project. I can run a file that uses a query file -- Al the query's and converters are in here -- without problems, but when I run a file that runs that file again, I get an error that the db cant be found.

```
so: 
Queryfile() : No problem,
Queryfile() -> Actionfile() : No problem,
Queryfile() -> Actionfile() -> action_manager(): Error, cant find db,
Queryfile() -> Actionfile() -> action_manager() -> startupfile(): Giant error, no way to solve it.
```

My goal is to build a startup file in the main dir and trigger all needed scripts from there, but I constantly receive this error:

```
    (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
('ERROR_LOADING_ANALYSES', OperationalError('(sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file'))
```

This is really bad and I don't know what i need to to make this project run. If there is any alternative way, for example move the workdirectory to this file, run it and move back, I would like to know it. Please let me know how you are dealing with this.

this is my project tree.

```
├───core_data
│   ├───data_temp
│   ├───**DATABASE**
├───core_update
│   ├───update_main
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───update_additional_scripts
│   │   └───__pycache__
├───core_utils
│   ├───database_querys
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───database_tables
│   │   └───__pycache__
├───startup file 
├───constants.
```

Look forward to your reply.

Comment: 1st guess- either use absolute path to your sqlite file or do relative path calculations based on the __file__ variable of a file in a known relationship with the sqlite file.  I'd need to see how you launch your app (`python script.py` vs `python folder/script.py`) & the connection string to know if I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to move the project work directory to the start of you folder and at the paths to the system paths.